# Kivy: AttributeError: 'Label' object has no attribute 'a'

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have made a simple app that has two timers that run simultaneously. One counts up, while the other counts down.

I originally tried stating "text: str(round(self.a, 1))" indented under Label and the error stated in the title would arise. I have now solved the issue by adapting my code as shown below (the changes were made in the .kv file section at the end):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from random import randint
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class PleaseWork(BoxLayout):
    a = NumericProperty(randint(3,7))
    b = NumericProperty(0)

    def start(self):

        self.anim = Animation(a=0, duration=self.a)
        self.anim &= Animation(b=15, duration=15)
        self.anim.repeat = True
        self.anim.start(self)


class PleaseApp(App):
    def build(self):
        p = PleaseWork()
        p.start()
        return p

if __name__ == "__main__":
    PleaseApp().run()


<PleaseWork>
    orientation: 'vertical'
    text_1: str(round(self.a, 1))
    text_2: str(round(self.b, 1))
    Label:
        text: root.text_1
    Label:
        id: count_up
        text: root.text_2
```

Whilst the code now does what it is supposed to do, my question is why has this rectified the error? I don't really understand why this has made a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the scope of the variables, in .kv there are at least the following ways to access an element:

### -  `id`:

```
<A>:
   id: a
   property_a: b.foo_property
   <B>: 
       id: b
       property_b: a.bar_property
```

It is used to reference any node in the tree.

### - `self`:

```
<A>:
    property_a: self.foo_property
    B:
        property_b: self.bar_property
```

When `self` is used, it means that the same node refers to itself, in the previous example `property_b: self.bar_property` it is pointed out that the property of `property_b` of`b` will take the same value as `bar_property` of`b` . It has the same use as in python classes.

### - `root`:

```
<A>:
    B:
        property_b: root.bar_property

<C>:
    D:
        property_d: root.bar_property
```

Use `root` when referencing the root of the tree, for example`property_b: root.bar_property` indicates that the `property_b` of`b` will take the same value as `bar_property` from`a`. And in the case of `property_d: root.bar_property` it indicates that`property_d` of `d` will have the same value as`bar_property` of `c`.

---

Considering the above, the following are also solutions:

1.

```
<PleaseWork>
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        text: str(round(root.a, 1))
    Label:
        id: count_up
        text: str(round(root.b, 1))
```

2.

```
<PleaseWork>
    orientation: 'vertical'
    id: please_work
    Label:
        text: str(round(please_work.a, 1))
    Label:
        id: count_up
        text: str(round(please_work.b, 1))
```